# React does not rerender on updated state of nested array

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks, state

I have an array of objects like so:

```
const [categories, setCategories] = React.useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Top Picks',
      subTitle: "Today's hottest stuff",
      images: [],
      searchQuery: 'shoes',
    },
...]);
```

Which I update with values in useEffect once like so:

```
React.useEffect(() => {

    const newCategories = categories.map(category => {

      fetch(`https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=${category.searchQuery}&per_page=10`, {
        headers: {
          'Authorization': apiKey,
        },
      }).then(r => {

        r.json().then(convertedJson => {

          category.images = convertedJson.photos;
        });
      });

      return category;
    });

    setCategories(newCategories);
  }, []);
```

however the child components here never rerender and I cannot figure out why. My understanding is that .map creates a new array anyhow, so the spread syntax isn't necessary in setCategories() but regardless it does not work.

```
{categories.map((category, i) => (
        <CategorySlider {...category} key={i}/>
      ))}
```

Comment: It _does_ rerender but with the old `categories`. You'd need to call `setCategories` once all `fetch` calls settled.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few issues but the primary issue I see is you're returning the `category` before the fetch can complete - so even when those `fetch` calls inside your `map` complete, you already returned the `category` below before the fetch completes.

Try using the `.finally()` block:

```
React.useEffect(() => {

  const newCategories = categories.map(category => {
    const c = {...category}; // <--- good practice
    fetch(`https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=${category.searchQuery}&per_page=10`, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': apiKey,
      },
    }).then(r => {
      r.json().then(convertedJson => {
        category.images = convertedJson.photos;
      });
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    }).finally(() => {
      return category;
    });
  });

  setCategories(newCategories);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! Using setState before the promises resolved was indeed the problem. The solution looks like this now:

```
 React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchImages() {
      const promises = categories.map(async category => {
        const response = await fetch(
          `https://api.pexels.com/v1/search?query=${category.searchQuery}&per_page=10`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: apiKey,
            },
          }
        );
        const convertedJson = await response.json();
        category.images = convertedJson.photos;
        return category;
      });
      setCategories(await Promise.all(promises));
    }
    fetchImages();
  }, []);
```